# Using loops to get and put an array of dictionaries from the Root level of a plist into a variable

Tags: swift, loops, dictionary

(Edited the title after releasing it's an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary of dictionaries)

I have a .plist of lots of dictionaries within the Root dictionary. All the dictionaries have the same keys ("image" and "text").

How can I get the keys and values from the .plist to put in a variable like a dictionary of dictionaries (with many more items eg. up to 100 images and text) as below?

var imageTextDict = [["image":"1-image", "text":"Text for 1"], ["image":"2-image", "text":"Text for 2"], ["image":"3-image", "text":"Text for 3"], ["image":"4-image", "text":"Text for 4"]]

Most code I found were either very old or didn't answer my question... The closest that I can get is to print the keys and values for a specific dictionary within the Root dictionary but not the full list from the Root.

In the .plist (Key)Root, (Type)Dictionary, (Value)eg. 100 items (I have less than 10 reputation so can't upload an image).

The .plist as source code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>image</key>
            <string>1-image</string>
            <key>text</key>
            <string>Text for 1</string>
        </dict>
        <key>2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>image</key>
            <string>2-image</string>
            <key>text</key>
            <string>Text for 2</string>
        </dict>
        <key>3</key>
        <dict>
            <key>image</key>
            <string>3-image</string>
            <key>text</key>
            <string>Text for 3</string>
        </dict>
        .
        .
        .
    </dict>
</plist>
```

The code below is based on [a tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJT2WlB03D0), the newest and simpliest I could find but not quite what I want...

In the Combo.plist file

```swift
struct dict: Decodable {
    let image: String
    let text: String
}

struct Config: Decodable {
    let dict: dict
}

struct ConfigValues {
    static func get() -> Config {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Combo", withExtension: "plist") else {
            fatalError("Could not find Combo.plist in your Bundle")
        }
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
            return try decoder.decode(Config.self, from: data)
        } catch let err {
            fatalError(err.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

In the ViewController.swift file
I tried to print different things, but can't print the whole array of dictionaries from the root.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print("Print \(ConfigValues.get().dict)")
        print("Print \(ConfigValues.get().dict.image)")
        print("Print \(ConfigValues.get().dict.text)")
        print("Print \(ConfigValues.get().self)")
        //using a closed range operator ... to create a range that goes from 1 to 100
        for i in 1...100{
            print(i)
        }
    }
```

Any direction is appreciated. Should I use numbers 1,2,3... as the keys in dictionaries? How can I get the total number of Root dictionary items in code to iterate through with loops or map? Thanks.

Comment: If you really have all the numbers, what about using an Array at top level (root level) instead?

Comment: I changed from using an array at the Root level to a dictionary after seeing someone used that in a similar situation. Is var imageTextDict = [["image":"1-image", "text":"Text for 1"], ["image":"2-image", "text":"Text for 2"], ["image":"3-image", "text":"Text for 3"], ["image":"4-image", "text":"Text for 4"]] means dictionaries within a dictionary or dictionaries within an array? Thanks.

Comment: The code you gave is an array of dictionaries

Comment: I just changed the Root to an array as suggested. Judging from the xml, I guess if translated into a variable, var imageTextDict = [["image":"1-image", "text":"Text for 1"], ["image":"2-image", "text":"Text for 2"], ["image":"3-image", "text":"Text for 3"]] means dictionaries within an array (not dictionaries within a dictionary)?

Comment: Great thanks. That's a start.

Comment: Does defining it as this help?
struct Config: Decodable {
    let dicts: [dict]
}

Comment: Fixed now with vadian's answer below, did use static func get() -> [Combo] { } So [ ] has something to do with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments change the root object to an array of dictionaries

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>image</key>
        <string>1-image</string>
        <key>text</key>
        <string>Text for 1</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>image</key>
        <string>2-image</string>
        <key>text</key>
        <string>Text for 2</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>image</key>
        <string>3-image</string>
        <key>text</key>
        <string>Text for 3</string>
    </dict>
       .
       .
       .
</array>
</plist>
```

---

Delete `Config` and use only one struct

```
struct Combo : Decodable {
    let image: String
    let text: String
}


struct ConfigValues {
    static func get() throws -> Config {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Combo", withExtension: "plist") else {
            fatalError("Could not find Combo.plist in your Bundle")
        }

        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        return try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Combo].self, from: data)
    }
}
```

And iterate the result

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    do {
       let combos = ConfigValues.get()
       for combo in combos {
           print(combo.image, combo.text)
       }
    } catch { print(error) }
 }
```